# Mysql How to select parent rows

Tags: mysql, sql

**Sample Data**:

| id | parent | text1 | text2 | ... | textN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | text1 | text2 | ... | ... |
| 2 | 1 | text3 | sdfsdf_text4 | ... | ... |
| 3 | 1 | text5 | text4 | ... | ... |
| 4 | 0 | text1 | text2 | ... | ... |
| 5 | 4 | text3 | adsfads_text4 | text5 | ... |

I need a query to find text using `LIKE '%text4%'` and get only `parent = 0` rows.

**Expected Output**:

| id | parent | text1 | text2 | ... | textN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | text1 | text2 | ... | ... |
| 4 | 0 | text1 | text2 | ... | ... |

I'm trying

```sql
SELECT * FROM `table` AS P /*parents*/
INNER JOIN `table` AS C /*childs*/
ON (C.id = P.id) 

WHERE ( 
    
    (
        ((P.`text1` LIKE '%text4%')OR (P.`text2` LIKE '%text4%')OR (P.`text3` LIKE '%text4%')OR (P.`text4` LIKE '%text4%'))
    )
        OR (
            (C.`parent`>0) AND (
                ((C.`text1` LIKE '%text4%')OR (C.`text2` LIKE '%text4%')OR (C.`text3` LIKE '%text4%')OR (C.`text4` LIKE '%text4%'))
            )
                                
        )
    ) 

GROUP BY CASE WHEN C.`parent`>0 THEN C.`parent` ELSE P.`id` END
```

have result - rows ids 2,3,5

how to get parent rows (e.g. where `parent` = 0), when parent or childs has 'text4'

[my table result's screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAY6p.png)

I need add row id=6525, and no id=6654
row 6525 don't contain 'text4', but childs have

Comment: Can you share you best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: I've append coding attempt

Answer (score 0):

How about ...

```
SELECT * FROM  <table> WHERE text1 LIKE '%text4%' AND parent = 0
```

... or, to include a search of the child table ...

```
SELECT P.* FROM <ParentTable> AS P
INNER JOIN <ChildTable> AS C ON 
(C.id = P.id) AND (C.parent = 0)
```

Comment: I need search at child's also AND get only parent=0 rows

Comment: @Dimitry S. - A second query was added to my answer per your comment.